# Proof that Diagonal is the shortest route?

Tags: geometry

Pythagoras'theorem doesn't feel sufficient to prove that the diagonal is the the shortest route. It only computes that distance. So is there a way to prove that a diagonal is the shortest route? It seems very intuitive. However, I wanted to see a mathematical proof.

Could the triangle inequality be used?

Comment: You are correct in pointing out that the Pythagorean theorem along is not sufficient to prove that "the diagonal" is the shortest route. What you need to prove is that a straight line segment gives the shortest length between two points. (This, of course, depends on what your starting assumptions/axioms are.) This is actually a common intro exercise in calculus of variations, but I'm sure there are more elementary proofs (I haven't thought about this too much so this is why I am writing this as a comment).